# How to exclude jars during overlay

Tags: java, maven

I have two applications - **A and B**.

In Application A there are some jars say J1,J2,J3.
And in Application B there is overlay and dependency of Application A. But I don't want jar J2 in application B.

How to exclude jar J2 ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for isn't possible. If Application B has dependencies on application A; and A depends on J2 - how do you think you can run "B" without providing J2?

The only thing that can work: if you can further slice your applications; it might be possible to come up with some component B'; where B' depends on A'; and A' does not depend on J2. Then you can package B' without J2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Maven dependency exclusions as described [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

However, bear in mind that you might face ClassNotFoundExceptions at runtime if the class required is no longer present.